# How to clear the Google+ server cache (social sharing)?

Tags: caching, google-plus

This question has been answered before in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618716/google-plus-shows-older-version-of-page), but there didn't seem to be any answer pointing out a URL where you can enter your personal website URL to have the cache cleared so that images are fetched next time you share to Google+ from your website.

Anyone know of any such site?

So far the suggestions I've found include:

- Change the image name so that the image is fetched anew.
- Change the image URL in the HTML attribute code for the image URL (e.g. by appending a query parameter such as `?&amp;version=v1`).

But I would like to not change this every time, and clear the Google+ cache instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Come on Google+, this is unacceptable. The analogous [Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) works great for clearing that cached 404.

Comment: I believe I've come across the issue now myself - images for older items are shared, but new item images don't get shared. Did you figure out how to clear this cache in the end?

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic button to clear the Google+ +snippet cache. In general it should respect the caching headers of your content so during testing/development you can turn those way down (just remember to turn them back on when you are done).

Comment: What caching headers? I have no control over HTTP headers. All I can do is modify meta tags in my HTML code, and I would like the Google+ to update themselves accordingly, via some mechanism of arranging for the HTML files and images listed in their meta tags to be scraped, but you say there is no button that would allow me to do so. It seems all I can do is upload the correct W3C compliant HTML and images and just hope they look good once they're there?

Comment: The [standard HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) used to control caching. Google also has a [rich data testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) that I think avoids the cache Google+ uses.

Comment: The page you mention talks about the HTTP (browser) cache. The problem is not the browser cache, which I have cleared anyways. The problem is the server cache on Google+ servers, which what I'm trying to clear.

Comment: Google's servers are still a client of your site and should respect the caching headers.

Comment: OK, then I would like to know the following: (1) if the information has already been cached, then can I send an HTTP header to delete such cached data? (2) What HTTP header should I send to tell the server not to cache the data? And (3) How do I do this from within a PHP script (at the beginning of the script before the HTML is sent to the client)? Thanks.

Comment: 1) You have to wait for the client to fetch the content again with the new caching headers. 2) all the commonly used caching headers where in the link from my earlier comment 3) There are many google results for "php set cache header"

Comment: So, the headers for preventing caching had to be implemented before the first scrape of my website by Google+. Even if I set <?php header("Cache-Control: no-store"); ?> in my code, it won't have any immediate effect if the next scrape is scheduled for a week from now. Less than ideal.

Comment: Anyways, I've used the Structured Data Testing Tool you mentioned. It downloads everything correctly, including my images, but does not display them, and I need to see how these would appear on the Goolge+ share page, so as it stands the tool does not seem very useful (unless I'm still missing something).

Comment: @abraham what exactly do you need to add to your headers to clear the Google's share cache?

Comment: You can't add headers to clear Google's cache. You set headers for how long the response should be cached and Google will not cache it for longer than the time specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CMS with clean URLs, then you could just install a redirect module and change the URL. The redirect module should automatically redirect from the old URL to the new one... At least that's what I've done when I forgot to test with the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) first and it works. It's a bit ugly but you should always be able to find a way to edit your URL to something that's very similar and still includes your keywords and such.

With Wordpress, I use the `Custom Permalink` and `Redirection` plugins.

For Drupal, I have the `Clean URLs` turn ON and used the `Global Redirect` module (now there is a `redirect` module, but it looks like it's not maintained...)